# Difference between $(this) and event.target?

Tags: jquery, this, jquery-events

I was making tabbed panels, following the tutorial in **JavaScript and jQuery : The Missing Manual**, there's that first line when the author does this:

```
   var target = $(this);
```

But I tried to do it that way

```
   var target = evt.target;
```

and I got that error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Object http://localhost/tabbedPanels/#panel1 has no method 'attr'

And when I changed `evt.target` back to `$(this)`, it worked like a charm.

I want to know what's the difference between `$(this)` and `evt.target` ?

Here's my code in case you needed it :

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tabbed Panel</title>
        <style>
            body {
               width : 100%;
               height: 100%;
            }
            
            #wrapper {
                margin : auto;
                width : 800px;                
            }
            
            #tabsContainer {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            
            #tabs {                
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }                
            
            #tabs li {
                float : left;
                list-style:none;
            }
            
            #tabs a {
                text-decoration:none;
                padding : 3px 5px;                
                display : block;                
            }
            
            #tabs a.active {
                background-color : grey;                
            }            
            #panelsContainer {
                clear: left;
            }            
            #panel1 {
                color : blue;
            }            
            #panel2 {
                color : yellow;
            }
            #panel3 {
                color: green;
            }
            #panel4 {
                color : black;
            }         
            
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>        
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="tabsContainer">
                <ul id="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#panel1">Panel1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel2">Panel2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel3">Panel3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#panel4">Panel4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="panelsContainer">
                <div id="panel1" class="panel">
                    this is panel1
                </div>
                <div id="panel2" class="panel">
                    this is panel2
                </div>
                <div id="panel3" class="panel">
                    this is panel3
                </div>
                <div id="panel4" class="panel">
                    this is panel4
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

**script.js :**

```
$(function(){
    $("#tabs a").click(function(evt){
       var target = evt.target,
           targetPanel = target.attr("href");
       $(".panel").hide();
       $("#tabs a.active").removeClass("active");
       target.addClass("active").blur();
       $(targetPanel).fadeIn(300);
       evt.preventDefault();
    });
    
    $("#tabs a:first").click();
})
```

Comment: `this` is a reference to the JavaScript DOM element. `$()` is the format provided by jQuery to turn the DOM element into a jQuery Object. using `evt.target` you're referencing an element, whereas with `$(this)` you're referencing an object with parameters that we have access to.

Comment: you could do `$(evt.target)` and (in this case) end up with the same results as well. The `.attr()` method is provided by the jQuery Object, not the element itself

Answer (score 348, accepted):

There **is** a difference between `$(this)` and `event.target`, and quite a significant one. While `this` (or `event.currentTarget`, see below) always refers to the DOM element the listener was attached to, `event.target` is the actual DOM element that was clicked. Remember that due to event bubbling, if you have

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

and attach click listener to the outer div

```
$('.outer').click( handler );
```

then the `handler` will be invoked when you click inside the outer div as well as the inner one (unless you have other code that handles the event on the inner div and stops propagation).

In this example, when you click inside the inner div, then in the `handler`:

- `this` refers to the `.outer` DOM element (because that's the object to which the handler was attached)
- `event.currentTarget` also refers to the `.outer` element (because that's the *current target* element handling the event)
- `event.target` refers to the `.inner` element (this gives you the element where the event originated)

The jQuery wrapper `$(this)` only wraps the DOM element in a jQuery object so you can call jQuery functions on it. You can do the same with `$(event.target)`.

Also note that if you rebind the context of `this` (e.g. if you use Backbone it's done automatically), it will point to something else. You can always get the actual DOM element from `event.currentTarget`.

Answer (score 42):

`this` is a reference for the DOM element for which the event is being handled (the current target). `event.target` refers to the element which initiated the event. They were the same in this case, and can often be, but they aren't necessarily always so.

You can get a good sense of this by reviewing the [jQuery event docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/), but in summary:

> **event.currentTarget**
>
> The current DOM element within the event bubbling
>   phase.
>
> **event.delegateTarget**
>
> The element where the currently-called jQuery
>   event handler was attached.
>
> **event.relatedTarget**
>
> The other DOM element involved in the event, if any.
>
> **event.target**
>
> The DOM element that initiated the event.

To get the desired functionality using jQuery, you must wrap it in a jQuery object using either: `$(this)` or `$(evt.target)`.

The `.attr()` method only works on a jQuery object, not on a DOM element. `$(evt.target).attr('href')` or simply `evt.target.href` will give you what you want.

Comment: They are **not** necessarily both references to the same element. See Petr's answer.

Comment: True enough, thanks for pointing that out. It's always interesting re-reading my old answers...

Answer (score 12):

There is a significant different in how jQuery handles the this variable with a "on" method

```
$("outer DOM element").on('click',"inner DOM element",function(){
  $(this) // refers to the "inner DOM element"
})
```

If you compare this with :-

```
$("outer DOM element").click(function(){
  $(this) // refers to the "outer DOM element"
})
```

Comment: Your answer is clear, concise, and provided exactly the information I needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

http://api.jquery.com/on/ states:

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the
>   element **where the event is being delivered**; for directly bound events
>   `this` is the element where the event was attached and for delegated
>   events `this` is an element matching selector. (Note that `this` may not
>   be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant
>   element.)
>
> To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be
>   used with jQuery methods, use $( this ).

If we have

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value ="btn1">
<input type="button" class="btn" value ="btn2">
<input type="button" class="btn" value ="btn3">

<div id="outer">
    <input type="button"  value ="OuterB" id ="OuterB">
    <div id="inner">
        <input type="button" class="btn" value ="InnerB" id ="InnerB">
    </div>
</div>
```

Check the below output:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".btn").on("click",function(event){
            console.log($(this));
            console.log($(event.currentTarget));
            console.log($(event.target));
        });


        $("#outer").on("click",function(event){
            console.log($(this));
            console.log($(event.currentTarget));
            console.log($(event.target));
        })
    })
</script>
```

Note that I use `$` to wrap the dom element in order to create a jQuery object, which is how we always do.

You would find that for the first case, `this` ,`event.currentTarget`,`event.target` are all referenced to the same element.

While in the second case, when the event delegate to some wrapped element are triggered, `event.target` would be referenced to the triggered element, while `this` and `event.currentTarget` are referenced to where the event is delivered.

For `this` and `event.currentTarget`, they are exactly the same thing according to http://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/

Comment: "For this and event.currentTarget, they are exactly the same thing according to"..actually not the same thing..
$("outer DOM element").on('click',"inner DOM element",function(){
  $(this) // refers to the "inner DOM element"
})

In this case currentTarget refers to "outer DOM element" whereas $(this) refers to "inner dom element"

Answer (score 4):

There are cross browser issues here.

A typical non-jQuery event handler would be something like this :

```
function doSomething(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        target = target.parentNode;
    //do stuff here
}
```

jQuery normalises `evt` and makes the target available as `this` in event handlers, so a typical jQuery event handler would be something like this :

```
function doSomething(evt) {
    var $target = $(this);
    //do stuff here
}
```

A hybrid event handler which uses jQuery's normalised `evt` and a POJS target would be something like this :

```
function doSomething(evt) {
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        target = target.parentNode;
    //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within an event handler function or object method, one way to access the properties of "the containing element" is to use the special this keyword. The this keyword represents the owner of the function or method currently being processed. So:

- For a global function, this represents the window.
- For an object method, this represents the object instance.
- And in an event handler, this represents the element that received the event.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function mouseDown() {
            alert(this);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p onmouseup="mouseDown();alert(this);">Hi</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The content of alert windows after rendering this html respectively are:

```
object Window
object HTMLParagraphElement
```

An Event object is associated with all events. It has properties that provide information "about the event", such as the location of a mouse click in the web page.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function mouseDown(event) {
            var theEvent = event ? event : window.event;
            var locString = "X = " + theEvent.screenX + " Y = " + theEvent.screenY;
            alert(event);
                    alert(locString);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p onmouseup="mouseDown(event);">Hi</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The content of alert windows after rendering this html respectively are:

```
object MouseEvent
X = 982 Y = 329
```

Answer (score 1):

'**this**' refers to the DOM object to which the event listener has been attached.
'**event.target**' refers to the DOM object for which the event listener got triggered.
A natural question arises as, why the event listener is triggering for other DOM objects.
This is because event listener attached parent triggers for child object too.