# why does stopPropagation take an event parameter in the callback instead of using 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I don't understand why, when using `stopPropagation()` or `stopDefault()` with jQuery, you have to introduce a param to the callback in the event handler function.  How does the browser know what to pass in to that function?  Also, why doesn't using `this` work?

Here's the code that works. I've bolded/asterisked the part that is confusing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".see-photos").on("click", function(**event**) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest(".tour").find(".photos").slideToggle();
  });
  $(".tour").on("click", function() {
    alert("This should not be called");
  });
});
```

To me, it would make more sense this way.  Note there is no `event` param for the callback in the handler function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".see-photos").on("click", function() {
    $(this).stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest(".tour").find(".photos").slideToggle();
  });
  $(".tour").on("click", function() {
    alert("This should not be called");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because [jQuerys' `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function passes the element who the event was fired from as `this`, not the event itself.

If you try to do the following:

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
   console.log(this);
});
```

You will see in your console the `<a>` tag that got clicked on. This is applicable to both the DOM `click` event as well as jQuery's. You can also see this `<a>` tag from `event.target`.*

If you want information about the event, then you need to inject it into your function as you've done so in your question:

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

This way, all of your event information is found in `event`. Likewise, it is only logical that you would stop propagating the event *itself*, as the element isn't propagating anywhere.

[**That being said, `this` and `event.target` are *not* the same**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21667010/1007638)

Comment: Great answer- thank you! And thanks for the further reference re: this/event.target!