# how to know the element that performed the click in a checkbox list dynamically added (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to add a list of checkboxes dynamically. I then need to know which one performed the click, then ask if it's checked or not.

I have this code:

```
   $('#MyContainerOfChecksDiv').click( '.MySelectorClass', function(){

     if ("MyCheckClicked".is(':checked'))
       {
         //...here i need to use the label and id 
       }
    else{...}
    })
```

using "$(this)" i get the "MyDiv", obviously using `$(this).find('input:checkbox')` I get the whole list of checks.

I have to get this checkbox because I need to use its properties.

Comment: Your function is passed the click event information as a parameter. You can get the exact element clicked from that.

Comment: I think you might be mistaking [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler) for [`.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: Why are you passing `.MySelectorClass` to `.click`? If you're doing event delegation to dynamic elements, you have to use `.on()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a formal parameter to `click` handler and use it like this

```
$('#myDiv').click('.MySelectorClass', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(':checked')) {
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/hcc6029a/)
Also it's not quite clear to me how you distinguish dynamically added elements and static. Do you have different class for them? If so then you dynamic and static elements can have different handlers and this will be the way to tell whether it was created dynamically

Comment: thanks to everyone  i have the solution like this [fiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ys0ktym1/6/) , i was making some mistakes. just two more things
- in this case what's the difference between '$(e.target)' and '$(this)'
- i don't get the difference betweet '.on('click'...)' and '.click(...)'   
thanks again

Comment: `.click(handler)` is a shortcut for `on('click', handler)` . Read [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for details. `this` and `e.target` make difference when handler is attached to a parent element http://stackoverflow.com/a/21667010/4573999

Answer (score 0):

To delegate to dynamic elements you have to use `.on()`. The element that you clicked on will be in `this`.

```
$("#myDiv").on("click", ".MySelectorClass", function() {
    if (this.clicked) {
        // here you can use this.id
    } else {
        // ...
    }
});
```

You can't use `.click()` to delegate like you tried. You're just binding the click handler to the DIV, and the string `".MySelectorClass"` is being passed as additional data to the handler.

Comment: thank you it works can you tell me what's the difference please [my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/ys0ktym1/6/)

Comment: `e.target` is always the same as `this` in jQuery event handlers.