# Javascript function that can be used by many elements and then distinguish which element clicked it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

for example i have 12 div tags that each represent a month. when clicked each one will display another div for its month and hide all the other months divs

The 12 month divs have the class `month` in common. the sections that each contain content for that month have `month_section` in common and the name of the month they represent as uncommon.

my javascript code so far:

```
$("#January,#February,#March,#April").click(function(e)){
  $(".month").removeClass("highlight");
  $(".month_sections").removeClass("show");
  $(".month_sections").addClass("hide");
  if(this == "#January"){(this).addClass("highlight");$(".january").addClass("show");}
  else if(this == "#February"){(this).addClass("highlight");$(".february").addClass("show");}
  else if(this == "#March"){(this).addClass("highlight");$(".march").addClass("show");}
  else if(this == "#April"){(this).addClass("highlight");$(".april").addClass("show");}
});
```

the if statement is not being correctly detected

Comment: can you include some of the html

Comment: Have u tried $(this) instead of this?

Comment: Inside the event handler, `this` will refer directly to the DOM node involved.  Your code already uses `this`, though incorrectly: `(this)` should be `$(this)`.

Comment: What you need is some sort of accordion plugin, try bootstrap accordion!

Comment: Also you have need to remove the extra ) here click(function(e)) -> click(function(e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler you are trying to compare the `this` object to a string.

The `this` in the context of the jQuery callback is the element that was clicked. If you wish to compare who was clicked you have to use `this.id` which in context of the first month will equal `January`. So you can compare.

```
if(this.id == "January") {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
    $(".january").addClass("show");
}
```

There are some other approaches you can take to save on some code.

```
$("#January,#February,#March,#April").click(function(e) {
    var monthStr = this.id;

    $(".month").removeClass("highlight");
    $(".month_sections").removeClass("show");
    $(".month_sections").addClass("hide");

    $(this).addClass("highlight");
    $("." + monthStr.toLowerCase()).addClass("show");
});
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: this is what i used, just for some reason the last line didnt overwrite the previous hide class so i had to add:    $("." + monthStr.toLowerCase()).removeClass("hide");    right before the last line.   PS thanks for the toLowerCase() that removes the need for if/else

Answer (score 1):

Use`e.target` as it refers to the element clicked on.

Note that this is not the same as using `$(this)`. Read more about that in this question's answer: [Difference between $(this) and event.target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077859/difference-between-this-and-event-target)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as your if statement:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') === 'January')
```

You could also use a switch statement if you need something special for each month:

```
switch ($(this).attr('id'))
{
   case 'January':
   case 'February':
...
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes in your code

You're comparing 'this' with the id of an element, this is the javascript object and not the id of the element

addClass is a jQuery method, you must refer to it as '$(this)'

Try this

```
$("#January,#February,#March,#April").click(function(e)) {
    $(".month").removeClass("highlight");
    $(".month_sections").removeClass("show");
    $(".month_sections").addClass("hide");
    if (this.id == "January") {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        $(".january").addClass("show");
     } 
    else if (this.id == "February") {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        $(".february").addClass("show");
    } 
    else if (this.id == "March") {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        $(".march").addClass("show");
    } 
    else if (this.id == "April") {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
        $(".april").addClass("show");
    }
});
```

NOTE: If you use e.target.id or $(this).attr('id') instead of this.id, any of these should work