# Simply which perform faster "click target" or "DOM matches"

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, click

What i am trying here to select a parent div with #missingRecord. Which performs better keeping CPU low :D

**Click Target:**

```
 if ( $(e.target).parents("#missingRecord").length) { 

        }
```

**Dom matches**

```
if($(this).closest().attr("id") == "missingRecord") {



}
```

Comment: Does it really matter? If yes, use `if(e.target.closest('#missingRecord'))`  See [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)  *note:* IE not supported but...

Comment: CPU? Really, doing this operation with any modern computer (or phone) it shouldn´t matter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me tell you, `e.target` and `this` doest **not alway represent the same object.**

And i don't think `e.target` and `this` will have any performance difference. As accessing a variable is a very very **low computation** operation (though that depends on the size of variable)

Let me tell you the difference though between `$(this)` and `event.target`, and quite a significant one. While `this` (or `event.currentTarget`, see below) always refers to the DOM element the listener was attached to, `event.target` is the actual DOM element that was clicked. Remember that due to event bubbling, if you have

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

and attach click listener to the outer div

```
$('.outer').click( handler );
```

then the `handler` will be invoked when you click inside the outer div as well as the inner one (unless you have other code that handles the event on the inner div and stops propagation).

In such a case, inside the `handler`, `this` (and `event.currentTarget`) would refer to the `.outer` DOM element, and `event.target` would refer to the `.inner` element.

The jQuery wrapper `$(this)` only wraps the DOM element in a jQuery object so you can call jQuery functions on it. You can do the same with `$(event.target)`.

Also note that if you rebind the context of `this` (e.g. if you use Backbone it's done automatically), it will point to something else. You can always get the actual DOM element from `event.currentTarget`.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21667010/1496715)