# .focus() not working on textarea in hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, focus, textarea

So I have this code here.

```
timeline.afterMilestonePrototypeCreated = function() {
    $(MILESTONE_PROTOTYPE_SELECTOR).hover(function(e){
       $(this).find('textarea').focus();
    });
}
```

Which should focus the textarea element after it was created. Everything works fine, I've even checked if the event is being called, after creation and hovering. Every other code works, but I'm not able to focus that textarea element. After some googling I've tried to add a setTimeout, which didn't work neither.

Thanks!

**SOLVED:**

The parent element of the textarea is a dot, and after hovering the dot it becomes a bigger circle and than it's inner elements are becoming visible. The problem was, that when adding the timeout the duration I've set was to short so the css transition for making the textarea visible  was still going that's way it wasn't focusing.

Comment: Can you show your HTML? What does `console.log($(this).find('textarea').length)` show?

Comment: It says "1". The html of the part that is added dynamically looks like this.

<div class="milestone prototype marker bigger-a" data-thedate="24-01-2016 02:00">
<textarea></textarea>
        </div>

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mjof31vn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

`$(this).find('textarea').focus();`

Try this:

`$(e.target).find('textarea').focus();`

Comment: Isn't `this` always the same as `e.target` in a jQuery event handler?

Comment: @Barmar There is a difference between $(this) and event.target. While this (or event.currentTarget, see below) always refers to the DOM element the listener was attached to, event.target is the actual DOM element that was clicked. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21667010/1179430

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda In that case, isn't `$(this)` more correct? When you hover over a DIV that contains other elements, `e.target` will be the other elements until the event bubbles up to the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, as long as `$(this).find('textarea')` works as expected:

```
timeline.afterMilestonePrototypeCreated = function() {
    $(MILESTONE_PROTOTYPE_SELECTOR).hover(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).find('textarea').focus();
    });
}
```

A hover event triggers a `focus` event, so preventing it will allow the manual `focus` to occur.

Comment: That didn't work either. Maybe it has something to do with the css that is hiding the visibility of the textarea once the parent element isn't hovered anymore?

Comment: Why does a hover event trigger a focus event? Where does it set the focus to?

Comment: @Barmar many events trigger a focus, including click and hover, but I have no idea why...

Comment: Solved the problem. The parent element of the textarea is a dot, and after hovering the dot the dot is becoming a bigger circle and than it's inner elements are becoming visible. The problem was, that when adding the timeout the duration I've set was to short so the css transition for making the textarea visible  was still going that's way it wasn't focusing.

Comment: @tyler_house Happy to hear you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help !