# How to differentiate the click event based on clicked DOM node?

Tags: javascript, methods, jquery-click-event

How can I change the method's behavior based on which node was clicked? I want to change the `data` attribute's `value` to `0` if the `$('.parent')` was clicked.

```
$('.parent').on('click', function (event) {
    this.someClickFunction(event);
});

$('.child').on('click', function (event) {
    this.someClickFunction(event);
});

someClickFunction: function (event) {
    //TODO: If $('.parent') was clicked, change to 0
    $('.holder').data('type', 1);
}
```

Comment: If($('.parent') == event.target ) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.is(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check which element was clicked.

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

For simplicity I have passed the function reference to click handler.

```
$('.parent').on('click', this.someClickFunction);
$('.child').on('click', this.someClickFunction);


someClickFunction: function (event) {
    $('.holder').data('type', $(event.target).is('.parent') ? 1: 0);        
}
```

A good read [Difference between $(this) and event.target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077859/difference-between-this-and-event-target)