# jQuery - Event extension to get event target or parent of specific type

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling

Using a glyph library like [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), buttons often end up looking something like this:

```
<button>
    <span class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-lg"></span> Click me
</button>
```

When handling a button event, the target can be either the span or the button itself, depending on where the user clicks, so I normally end up with something like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function($event) {

    var $target = $($event.target);
    var $button = $target.is('button') ? $target : $target.closest('button');

    // useful stuff goes here
}
```

Is it possible to extend the jQuery event object to add a method that encapsulates this functionality, so it can be called like this?

```
var $button = $event.getSpecificTarget('button');
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsayce/63njsdjb/) to demonstrate the issue.

It could be done using a normal jQuery plugin, but it would feel cleaner if it could be accessed straight from the event object, rather than via a plugin like this:

```
var $button = $.getSpecificTarget($event, 'button');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the event to the document, instead of what you are doing now.

```
$(function () {

  $(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
    var button = $(this);
    $('#result').append(button.text() + '<br>');
  });
});
```

Please, check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63njsdjb/10/).
You will see that the text of the `button` is appended to the `div` when you click the button itself or the span. The key is using `$(this)`.
In fact, you can keep the code as you have it and use `$(this)` to get the button.

Comment: Interesting... using your method, the event.target is still the span if you click on that, but $(this) always returns the button, regardless of where you click. I've always used event.target instead of $(this) as I thought it was more readable - I never realised there was a difference. Should have read this, I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21667010/13153