# jQuery filter for table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table but somehow now able to filter the row. Its giving me error as cannot read property split. Here is the link to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/1866/) file. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
$("#crudtable_filter").keyup(function () {
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#crudtable").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
    jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show();
}).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
    "color": "#C0C0C0"
});
```

Comment: Your  `this.value.split(" ");` get undefine value resolve it and proceed.

Answer (score 3):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sofqjbrg/3/

Explanation:

In order to get the value of the element that rigger the event, you need to use `$(event.target).val()`.

For the difference between `$(event.target)` and `$(this)`, please refer to [Difference between $(this) and event.target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077859/difference-between-this-and-event-target)

PS: Your focus event is registered to the wrong element.

Comment: thanx , worked like charm , but i can only see the specific element which i searched for , what if i want to see the entire row of the selected word?

Comment: @Harshit you may want to keep the table header by hiding all tr excpet the first one:  `var jo = $("#crudtable").find("tr").not(":eq(0)");`. New JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sofqjbrg/5/