# .after() method not displaying HTML string as HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to add a html div after paragraph on clicking the paragraph, but the after method is not taking the parameter as HTML string, rather it is taking it as normal text.

so on clicking I am getting:

```
This is a paragraph.
<div>sdfds</div>
```

rather than:

```
This is a paragraph.
sdfds
```

This is the function I am using:

```
function abc(e) {
    e.target.after("<div>sdfds</div>");
}
```

I am calling this function by:

```
<p onClick=abc(event)>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: There seems to be some confusion on the subject.  This is not jQuery.

Comment: @David it's not called as jquery, but could that be the issue?

Comment: @freedomn-m: Maybe?  There's no evidence that jQuery is being used or even loaded at all in this code.  Nothing here is using jQuery.

Comment: You may be right. It's sort of implied, but not clearly shown. my bad.

Comment: you are not using jquery function correctly, e.target is javascript object convert it to jquery object and call function after,
$(e.target).after('<div>sdfs</div>');

Comment: I guess it would be helpful if the OP could chime in and specify how/if jQuery is involved at all here.

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat: `"there is no function after() in javascript"` - There would appear to be: https://jsfiddle.net/3zocjj7d/

Comment: Sorry,this after just adds textnode, this willnot parse html,
try this https://jsfiddle.net/3zocjj7d/1/

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat "no `after()` function javascript" - I thought that at first as well, which is why I couldn't understand why the jquery parts were being removed.   Looked into it and it's fine, but as you say, adds a textnode. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after  maybe OP could use `insertAdjacentHTML` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're kind of mixing vanilla JavaScript with jQuery. Here's how to do it both ways:

**JavaScript**

```js
function abc(elem) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "Text";
  elem.after(div);
}
```

```html
<p onClick=abc(this)>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

**jQuery**

```js
$('p').click(function() {
  $(this).after('<div>Text</div>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Note that WRT the experimental native after() method as the [docs for .after()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after) state:

> The ChildNode.after() method inserts a set of Node or DOMString
>   objects in the children list of this ChildNode's parent, just after
>   this ChildNode. DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text
>   nodes.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function abc(e) {
  $(e.target).after("<div>Test</div>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p onClick=abc(event)>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21667010/7631470) for the difference between `e.target` and `$(e.target)`

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a native `after` function (which I honestly didn't know existed) with jQuery's `after` method. In your click handler, `e.target` is a native DOM Node which happens to have an [apparently non-standard] `after` method. This works differently than jQuery's method. If you wan't jQuery's behavior, you will need to turn your target into a jQuery wrapped element:

```
$(e.target).after('<div>...</div>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6n3gn57j/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uase javascript use innerHTML in youcase.

```
<p onClick=abc(event)>This is a paragraph.</p>
<script>
function abc(e) {
    e.target.innerHTML+=("<div>sdfds</div>");
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3zocjj7d/1/