# Accessing dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

When adding a dynamically added element, how can I get attributes for that element (when clicking on it, for example)?  I figured out that I need to delegate an event, but I still can't access any of the attributes of that event.

This JSFiddle shows the issue problem: https://jsfiddle.net/wgc499n9/

`$(this).data('index')` comes up as 'undefined' - I think `$(this)` is referencing 'document' instead of `.remove_link`; even the `event` data doesn't seem to have any useful information in it.  `$(this).attr('id')` also comes up as 'undefined'.

In the end, I just need to be able to click that `remove` link to remove the row it's on.  How can I accomplish that?  I even tried inline JS, but that caused even stranger behavior.

P.S. I also learned that my dynamically added `data-index` attribute is not stored in the DOM; jQuery stores it separately, so its containing element has to be accessed by using `.find()`...but I can't figure out how to use `.find()` to access the specific individual elements I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use element event(e) parameter instead this:

```js
let i = 0;
$('#add').on('click', () => {
  $('#container').append(`<div>row #${(i+1)} <a "href="#" data-index="${i}" class="remove_link">remove</a></div>`);
  i++;
})

$(document).on('click', '.remove_link', (e) => {
  //alert(JSON.stringify(e));
  alert($(e.target).data('index'));
})
```

```css
.remove_link {
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add row</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

For more detail read [difference b/w $(this) ans event.target.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077859/difference-between-this-and-event-target)

Comment: I did see elsewhere that you're supposed to use the `target` attribute of the click event.  But when I printed out the event details (using `JSON.stringify`), `target` showed up as an empty object, so I assumed it wouldn't work. :/

Answer (score 2):

In your event handler, `this` represent window. You have access to `e.target` to get the clicked element.

This should works:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.remove_link', (e) => {
    alert($(e.target).data('index'));
})
```