# jQuery click fires but no event passed

Tags: jquery, click

I have this:

```
<div id="pic_pin">
    <div id="selected_picture">
        <img src="map.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I add a marker picture on clicking the map image:

```
$('#selected_picture').on('click', function(e){
    offset = $('#selected_picture').offset();
    x = e.pageX - offset.left - 25;
    y = e.pageY - offset.top - 25;
    var pin = $('<div class="pin"><img class="pin-img" data-left="' + x + '" data-top="' + y + '" src="pin.png" /></div>');
    pin.uniqueId();
    $('#pic_pin').append(pin);
    pin.css('left', x).css('top', y).show();
});
```

Then on clicking the marker image (div) I want to open a pop-up:

```
$('#pic_pin').on('click', '.pin', function(e){
    console.log('log: '+e.target.id);
    ...
});
```

And the problem is the e.target.id is empty - it simply shows 'log: ', no `id` is shown. Why?

Comment: There is no id for elements with class `pin`

Comment: There is no id attribute on "pin" element.

Comment: Yes, they do, I set them with pin.uniqueId(); which I can see in the console Inspector. This is a copy from the Inspector: <div class="pin ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="ui-id-3" style="left: 124px; top: 11.0167px; display: block;"><img class="pin-img" data-left="124" data-top="11.01666259765625" src="pin.png"></div>

Comment: Have you tried `this.id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the `pin.uniqueId()` function call provides the `.pin` elements with `id` attributes, as they do not have them by default.

Assuming that's the case you need to use `this` or `e.currentTarget`, not `e.target`.

When using a delegated event handler `target` is the element which the event has bubbled to (`#pic_pin` in your case), whereas `this` and `currentTarget` refer to the element which raised the event.

Try this:

```js
$.fn.uniqueId = function() {
  $(this).prop('id', new Date().getTime());
}

$('#selected_picture').on('click', function(e) {
  offset = $('#selected_picture').offset();
  x = e.pageX - offset.left - 25;
  y = e.pageY - offset.top - 25;
  var pin = $('<div class="pin"><img class="pin-img" data-left="' + x + '" data-top="' + y + '" src="pin.png" /></div>');
  pin.uniqueId();
  $('#pic_pin').append(pin);
  pin.css('left', x).css('top', y).show();
});

$('#pic_pin').on('click', '.pin', function(e) {
  console.log('log: ' + e.currentTarget.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pic_pin">
  <div id="selected_picture">
    <img src="map.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: e.currentTarget.id worked too. Thank you very much for the explanation and help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this.id` or also `$(this).attr('id')` :

```
$('#pic_pin').on('click', '.pin', function(e){
    console.log('log: '+this.id);
    ...
});
```

When `this` inside the `click` context refer to the current clicked `pin`.

Comment: Yep, that's worked! Thanx a lot! What's the difference between this and e.target.id?

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help... take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077859/difference-between-this-and-event-target