# How can I get a reference to an element that has a common class on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following html structure:

`<div class ='wrapper'></div>`

`<div class ='wrapper'></div>` *I want to get this element*

`<div class ='wrapper'></div>`

I tried doing something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'wrapper', ()=>{
  var element = $(this); //not sure how to do this 
});
```

How can I get a reference to the clicked element so I can used it for things like `$(element).siblings()` and `next()`, etc.

The method that I tried to use, selects all the elements with that class, i want to get only the element clicked on, Is there a way I can do that ?

Comment: Read this regarding e.target and e.currentTarget  https://stackoverflow.com/q/12077859/8252164

Comment: afaik, `this` should refer to the clicked element in JQuery. But if you use an arrow function, it might not work since arrow functions have special rules for `this`. `event.target` is a nice non-jquery way of getting the reference if you need the `this` context to not refer to the element.

Comment: First add a dot: `$(document).on('click', '.wrapper',`

Comment: Nice catch!! @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".wrapper").click(function() {
    var clickedElement = $(this);
    alert(clickedElement.text());
    console.log(clickedElement.siblings());
    console.log(clickedElement.next());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>Click here One</div>
<div class='wrapper'>Click here Two</div>
<div class='wrapper'>Click here Three</div>
```

Comment: Explanation? You changed from ES6 to ES3 without explanation

Answer (score -1):

This is correct:

```
$(document).on('click', '.wrapper', function() {
  var element = $(this); //not sure how to do this 
});
```

but when you are referencing you should by

```
element.siblings()
```

and not by

```
$(element).siblings()
```

Comment: I was answering about refering

Comment: And $(this) is not what you think it is in the ES6 fat arrow function - that was the other big issue