# How can I target child of specific parent with hover effect using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to find out how to edit this jQuery code so that only the parent that is hovered shows its child. At the moment, all the children are shown when any parent is hovered.

Any help much appreciated.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbywjh7t/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
  $(".parent").hover(
    function () {
      $(".child").addClass("hover");
    },
    function () {
      $(".child").removeClass("hover");
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6px;
}

.child {
  width:inherit;
  height:30px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:blue;
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.child.hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By passing the the *context* as second argument

> **Selector Context** 
>   By default, selectors perform their searches within
>   the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context
>   can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to
>   the $() function.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $(".parent").hover(
    function() {
      $(".child", this).addClass("hover");
    },
    function() {
      $(".child", this).removeClass("hover");
    }
  );

});
```

**Working demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/a4sxc1up/

**CSS Only Solution**

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.child {
  width: inherit;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to transverse the direct child by using `$(this).find(".child")` like:

```
$(".parent").hover(
  function() {
     $(this).find(".child").addClass("hover");
  },
  function() {
     $(this).find(".child").removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/74zuqeky/)

Or, simply using `toggleClass()`:

```
$(".parent").hover(function() {
   $(this).find(".child").toggleClass("hover");
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/74zuqeky/1/)

Answer (score 1):

use `$(this).find(".child").addClass("hover");`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

$(".parent").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find(".child").addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(".child").removeClass("hover");
  }
);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your code like that:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $(".parent").hover(
  function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find(".child").addClass("hover");
  },
  function (e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find(".child").removeClass("hover");
  }
);

});
```

Comment: When you have `this` in this context what the use of event? Please explain

Comment: the best and complete answer to you question is finding in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21667010/4981637